# RxJS 5 filter: 2 combineLatest

Tags: angular, rxjs5

Using Angular, I am displaying a list (array) of data from the server. Above the list there is a `button bar` and `dropdown` that allows the user to `filter` the list.

I created 2 `Subjects` and used `combineLatest` in the stream like this:

```
this.http.get('/api')
    .combineLatest(this.firstFilter$.startWith(initialValue))
    .map(([data, firstFilter]) => _.filter(data, item => firstFilter === item.prop))
    .combineLatest(this.secondFilter$.startWith(initialValue))
    .map(([data, secondFilter]) => _.filter(data, item => secondFilter === item.prop))
```

Although this works, when debugging I noticed that when calling the secondFilter$.next() the firstFilter's map is not called... But it does still take into account both filters and displays proper data.

I am wondering if there is a better approach to handling 2 or more filters?

Answer (score 0):

This is a chain of events, once you filtered data first time - it wont be executed again:

data > filter 1 > data' > filter 2 > result

If your filters are not async, then it could be simplified to:

```
 this.http.get('/api')
 .map(data => _.filter(data, item => <check item to satisfy filters 1 and 2>))
```